# 3 div independently relative and top aligned

Tags: css, cross-browser, alignment

How to (top) align 3 div that should be relative to a previous div (but not between them)?
I can't use floats or `position:inline-block` (if you set `display:none` on 2 divs the last one shouldn't move).
`position:absolute` neither because there's a relative footer underneath.
`vertical-align:top` doesn't work using spans - any workaround?

I tried using a wrapper but it can't work cause the height of the divs is not fixed.
The height of the wrapper gets completely ignored anyway (by the following footer) unless Im using relative children.

Any ideas?

Comment: @meder imagine 3 lines: first line a div (100% width) - (underneath) second line 3 divs aligned on the bottom of the (first line) div - third line (the footer 100% width) // the hard part of my problem is the fact that the divs on the 2nd line shouldn't move if others get removed and the fact that the footer is relative (not covering the divs on the second line)

Comment: @brock already explained in the question: when you set `display:none` on one of the divs with inline-block or floats the other divs will move (except the first one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**
the order is important and the wrapper is optional (to position the side divs)

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
<div id="middle"></div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#left {float:left}
#middle {margin:0 auto}
#right {float:right}
#footer {clear:both}
```

unless someone comes up with something easier
ill accept my answer in 24h